# How to use hyperlinkedModelSerializer in django rest framework

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework

How to use hyperlinkedModelSerializer in django rest framework My output shows:

`HyperlinkedRelatedField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.

The code is given below:

```
serailizers.py

#Program Serializer

class ProgramSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Program
        fields = '__all__'

#Program MiniSerializer

class ProgramMiniSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

 programCode = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True,view_name='program-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Program
        fields = ('programCode', 'pro_name', 'url', 'DepartmentID')

viewsets.py

class ProgramViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Program.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProgramSerializer
    filterset_class = ProgramFilter
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    __basic_fields = ( 'programCode', 'pro_name','pro_shortForm', 'DepartmentID')
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter)
    filter_fields = ('programCode', 'DepartmentID')
    search_fields = ('DepartmentID')
    

    def list(self, request,  *args, **kwargs):
        programs = Program.objects.all()   
        serializer = ProgramMiniSerializer(programs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get_queryset(self): 
        programs = Program.objects.all()
        return programs

    def retrieve(self, request,  *args, **kwargs):
        params=kwargs
        print(params['pk'])
        # programs = Program.objects.all()
        programs = Program.objects.filter(DepartmentID = params['pk'])
        serializer = ProgramMiniSerializer(programs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Can you please also add view where you use ProgramMiniSerializer ?

Comment: Yes I have added the viewset.py file where ProgramMiniSerializer is used

Answer (score 0):

In `list` and `retrieve` methods where you initialize serializer, you need to pass context to it, like this:

```
serializer = ProgramMiniSerializer(
    programs, 
    many=True, 
    context={
        'request': request,
    },
)
```